# Explain the process of solving this nested squareroot problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, radicals

I am in class 10 and this is an olympiad question so I am having a problem doing this. The innermost one I have evaluated to be $\sqrt{15}- \sqrt2$. But the rest I don't know how to do.

$\sqrt { 2 + \sqrt { 3 } - \sqrt { 4 + \sqrt { 5 } + \sqrt { 17 - 4 \sqrt { 15 } } } }$

Comment: Wrong evaluation: $(\sqrt{15}-\sqrt2)^2\ne17-4\sqrt5$. Once you will have the correct evaluation, how to carry on with the previous to last square root should become obvious. And once you will have replaced the link to an image, your question will become self-contained, as it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well actually, the inner most evaluates to $(\sqrt{12}-\sqrt{5})$ and not what you said. You can solve such questions as:-

$$a^2+b^2=17$$
$$2ab=4\sqrt{15}$$
Solve these equations to get the desired result (Also, note that b is negative, but you can change these signs later knowing that there's $-2ab$ over there). It'll then evaluate to:-

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{12}-\sqrt{5}}}$$
$$=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}}$$
$$=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3}-1}$$
$$=1.$$

Comment: Thank you. I just realised why i was wrong.

Comment: @user642771 you're welcome